# Background image with a colored curved border at the bottom

Tags: css, svg, border, clip

I am trying to achieve this with `css3`, I tried using `border-radius` with percent values and it's not the same always, I always got a rounded corners and the border will start disappearing on the corners too.

I want it to be  exactly the same as the example image:

[image: Image link]

EDIT:
this is my html code :

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <section class='section-1'>
        <div class='container'>
        </div> 
    </section>
```

And this is my css:

```
.section-1 {
    background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can accomplish this using only CSS by creating a `<div>` that would be used only as a mask. You can create the round effect with the `border-radius` property, but you need to do it bigger than the part that will be visible, then crop the result to show only the curvy part that you want. And you must compensate the imagem position.

Check my example below:

```css
.oval-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative
}

.oval-header--mask {
  width: 200%; /* Mask width 2x the size of the header */
  height: 200%; /* Mask height 2x the size of the header */
  transform: translate(-25%, -51%); /* This compensates the size of the image and places the curvy part that you want on the certer of the mask, it's a translate that negativates half it's width and half it's height */
  border: 6px solid yellow;
  border-radius:  0 0 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.placecage.com/3000/1500');
  background-size: cover
}
```

```html
<div class="oval-header">
  <div class="oval-header--mask">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @MohamedEttayeb To give an answer more specific than mine I would need to know the width and height of the header, and even that I will be just assembling the code for you, the main ideia it's on my answer already.

Comment: i am working on the full screen the width is 100% and the height is dynamic

Comment: @MohamedEttayeb Ok, I've changed all my measures to relative ones, except for the height, that you can change it manually, see if it helps you. The placement of the image may change, you'll need to test that.

Comment: i am not having an image inside my html code, its a background image

Comment: can you maybe apply it on my html code ? cause i cant make it work

Comment: Your HTML should look like this then `<div class='container-fluid'><div class="oval-header">
  <div class="oval-header--mask">
  </div>
 </div></div>` and you can copy my css above and just replace the image's path